# Can't use @faker-js/faker in TypeScript project -- undefined -- but older "faker" import works. Why?

Tags: typescript, npm, undefined, faker.js

Right now I have:

```
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "@types/faker": "^5.5.3",
```

in my packages.json. I'm using 5.5.3 because there's another dependency in the project (codecept) that's locked to the older version.

The original faker project at https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker seems to have been abandoned. It has a joke version number, no description, etc.

I'd like to use the project that is actively maintained at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@faker-js/faker

But when I try:

- in my packages.json: `"@faker-js/faker": "^5.5.3"`
- importing it with: `import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';` (per faker-js documentation)
- call it like `faker.datatype.number(100);`

I get:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'datatype')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'datatype')
```

Weirdly, this same code works on a coworker's laptop.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried doing stuff like blowing away `node_modules` and starting fresh, and running `npm install`, but no luck.

Comment: Oh I just read you are literally using a different lib. Deleted my answer

Comment: Version 5.5.3 seems to use [default exports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@faker-js/faker/v/5.5.3)...?

Comment: @caTS when I try `const faker = require('faker');` I get `Cannot find module 'faker'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the import to `import faker from '@faker-js/faker'` should solve the problem since faker 5.5.3 uses default imports.

You will however get a compiler error, since this version of faker does not provide its own types. There is also no `@types` for this package and the types in `@types/faker` do not seem to match the `@faker-js/faker` package. So you can do `const faker = require('@faker-js/faker)` and continue without having types. But I would recommend to upgrage the `@faker-js/faker'` since the newer versions have TypeScript support out of the box.